# Why am I getting blocked requests on SSL with this?

Tags: django, ssl, request

Running Python 2.7, Django 1.97 on Windows 7 x64.

Running Django in SSL mode, seems like it blocks any new web requests while another is processing. It doesn't do this via regular HTTP though. To make sure it wasn't something wonky with my code I created a fresh project and tried it and got the same results.

Here is a proof of concept you too can build.

Create a new project called "testserver".

In the folder create a "templates" folder that contains two files, "index.html" and "bigfile.html". Make each contain representative text such as "this is the index" and "this is the bigfile page".

In settings.py these to the INSTALLED_APPS:

```
'sslserver',
'testserver'
```

Now in urls.py add this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$',"testserver.views.index"),
    url(r'^bigrequest/$',"testserver.views.bigrequest"),
    ]
```

Finally create views.py and write this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
import time

def index(request):
    return render_to_response("testserver/index.html")

def bigrequest(request):
    start_time=time.clock()
    randomvar=0
    while time.clock()-start_time<=30:
        randomvar+=1

    return render_to_response("testserver/bigrequest.html")
```

Now start the server NORMALLY with "python manage.py runserver".

Open the server's hostname without any additional URL(http://localhost:8000/). It will display index.

Now open http://localhost:8000/bigrequest/ The webpage will take thirty seconds to load and then show the bigrequest.html page normally. Now here is the tricky part: try reloading index while bigrequest is processing. Index will load immediately regardless of whether or not bigrequest is done or not.

However, now try the same test starting the server IN SSL MODE. Do "python manage.py runsslserver". Load the bigrequest page again. While it is loading, attempt to open index. Index WILL NOT RESPOND until bigrequest is done.

As you can guess a server that cannot process requests concurrently is a very bad setup. But then why do I have to forfeit SSL?

What is going on here?

Comment: It sounds like the `runsslserver` command is single threaded. You could try using `runserver_plus` from Django extensions. Note you shouldn't be using `runserver` or similar tools in production.

Comment: The `runsslserver` is rather meant to be a tool to use while developing. I would recommend using a webserver like nginx or Apache in front of your Django application.